# How to receive more data (greater than, >128) at once on ESP32 UART Rx PORT?

Tags: uart, fifo, esp32

I am Unable to receive more data, Only half of data is received on UART Port. What can I do to get full data ?

I tried changing H/W FIFo (in uart.h, espressif files) to full data length (256) from 128. It did not worked.

```
switch(event.type)
{   
    case UART_DATA: 

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Event DATA SIZE [UART DATA]: %d", event.size);                                   
    uart_read_bytes(UART_NUM_2, UART_event_data, event.size, portMAX_DELAY); 
    printf("Received data from QR Code is ........... %s\n", UART_event_data);
    break;
}
```

Expected Incoming data is of full length 256 B.

Comment: What version of the ESP-IDF are you using? And, what is the definition of UART_event_data and event.size?

Comment: Version is 4.0. UART_event_data is array which will have Incoming Data and event.size is size of event ( data in this case ).

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=8858 : "The FIFO's size (in byte) can be set in UART_MEM_CONF_REG configuring bits 7 to bit 10. (ESP32 TRM V4.0, page 364)
This register is 0x88 by default: 128 Byte TX FIFO and 128 byte RX FIFO. So bit 7 = 1 sets 128 Byte TX FIFO size."

Furthermore the author states that changing the size is not trivial. Long story short: your best bet is mostlikely to work around this limitation by collecting the message from the FIFO in parts and put them in another buffer together. Alternatively you can hope that they implemented a way to change the FIFO length by now. Further research in the esp forum/doc might help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a proper ISR and mark it `IRAM_ATTR` so that it's always in the cache.

In the ISR, copy the data from `uart_read_bytes` into a queue (`xQueueSendFromISR`) and don't do any other work, to keep the ISR small and fast.

Definitely *don't* call `printf` or `log` from an ISR. Create another (user) task and call `xQueueReceive` in a loop there, where you can print the data and do any other work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I am going with reading single byte till the string (expected data) ends. 
byte by byte.